# Animate changing backgrounds

Tags: html

I´m working on a project for college and I´m trying to imitate a effect on this page: https://u.gg/ for my homepage, I managed to change the backgrounds but now I´m trying to add a "fade" effect, any suggestions? Just found a way to add de 'fade' effecto but I need to match it with the intervals

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trip Guru</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="home" id="landing_home">
        <nav class="navbar bg-transparent">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Y0VvwJQ2/logo-white.png" class="logo" /></a>
        </nav>
    </div>


    <script src="main_script.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script> <!--Bootstrap JS-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body,html {
    height:100%;
}
.logo {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.home {
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:  cover;
}
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var header = $('#landing_home');

var backgrounds = new Array(

    'url(https://i.postimg.cc/nM76hD9j/bridge.jpg)'
  , 'url(https://i.postimg.cc/HV9RQ12T/lake.jpg)'
  , 'url(https://i.postimg.cc/686Scbjn/mountain.jpg)'
  , 'url(https://i.postimg.cc/qNmF5cSY/river.jpg)'
  , 'url(https://i.postimg.cc/Ff765dQK/villa.jpg)'
);

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.fadeTo("slow", 0.5)
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
    header.fadeTo("slow", 1)
}
setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);

header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zqtkme2x/

Comment: You will need to post an attempt at solving this in code, with a question about what is working or not working. See [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a solid SO question.

Comment: you can set opacity :0 to opacity:1 with interval to get the same fade effect

Comment: @Toby Just added the attempt, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function nextBackground() {
  header.animate({opacity: 0}, 0);
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;

    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow')

}


setInterval(nextBackground, 3000);

header.css('background-image',backgrounds[0]).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow')
```

[JQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
header.animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow')
```

The opacity value may need to be reset before you run it

```
header.animate({opacity: 0}, 0);
```

Comment: Looks perfect, I managed to get the same effect with the .fadeTo() method but I still needed to match the speed with the intervals.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this classes for animate things in my projects:

In a css file:

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.fast {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fadeIn {
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}
```

Then use for example

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
   <span> Hello </hello>
</div>
```

And you can use class fast to do the fadeIn fast.

```
<div class="animated fadeIn fast">
   <span> Hello </hello>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont know too much about animation but I really wanted to add something to give my proyect an extra feature :)

Comment: @Jeremy this is very simple and effective. Hope you can use it.