# Collapsed list overflowing

Tags: html, css

I am working on a school project and I just ran into a problem with a  which is collapsed into an input box (I will apply filter list later on) but when this list shows it overflows out of my landing screen and just looks bad. Does anyone have any suggestions to work this out I´m trying to imitate [this page](https://u.gg/) (notice how you can click on the input box and the list won't show until the user types something) I did my best to imitate it in my code?

[This is an image of my HTML](https://postimg.cc/fk9T0BSC/b58d16f9).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var header = $('#landing_home');

  var backgrounds = new Array(

    'url(Recursos/imagenes_bg/bridge.jpeg)', 'url(Recursos/imagenes_bg/lake.jpeg)', 'url(Recursos/imagenes_bg/mountain.jpg)', 'url(Recursos/imagenes_bg/river.jpeg)', 'url(Recursos/imagenes_bg/villa.jpeg)'
  );

  var current = 0;
  //Fuente para animar el fondo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547736/animate-changing-backgrounds , yo hice la pregunta por eso esta mi codigo ahi.
  function nextBackground() {
    header.animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    }, 0);
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    //header.fadeTo("slow", 0.5)
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 'slow');
    //header.fadeTo("slow", 1)
  }
  setInterval(nextBackground, 7000);

  header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]).animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 'slow');

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.logo {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.home {
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.text_home {
  color: white;
  font-size: 400%;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000000;
}

.form_home {
  text-align: center;
}

.form_home input[type=text] {
  width: 75%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000000;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.form_list {
  font-size: 150%;
}

.list-group {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.home_jumbo {
  background-color: #B1B1B1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Trip Guru</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="Content/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="home" id="landing_home">
    <nav class="navbar bg-transparent sticky-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="Recursos/Logo/logo_white.png" class="logo" /></a>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="text_home"> Decubre tu siguiente destino </h1>
    <div class="form_home">
      <input type="text" class="form_home" placeholder="Buscar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#paises" />
    </div>

    <ul class="list-group collapse text-center w-75 form_list" id="paises">
      <li class="list-group-item">Rusia</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Corea del Sur</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Japón</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Costa Rica</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Dubai</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Suecia</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Alemania</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Francia</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Brasil</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">China</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron-fluid home_jumbo">
    <h1 class="display-1">It overflows here</h1>
  </div>

  <script src="main_script.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!--Bootstrap JS-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made a partial solution: adding overflow:hidden on body,html and overflow:Scroll on my list-group, BUT I cant scroll through the listed items

Comment: @MrMaavin at least just say me what you had edit in this question.

Comment: @jeremy: you want to scroll horizontally or vertically.

Comment: Of course it does. Your `home` element is 100% and on top of that you add the `home_jumbo`, which then overflows.

Comment: I added it just to show where it was overflowing, when it overflows it creates a white canvas, which just broke the design I was looking for

Comment: Well, what you added has nothing to do with your list, and will put users completely off with what you are asking. Instead increase the list with enough items and make that overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correct you just need to insert this part, on the `open` part:

```
max-height: 500px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

this will create a limitation in the size and makes the overflow only in the vertical

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it using this. It hiddes when it overflows vertically and lets you scroll.

```
.list-group {
cursor:pointer;
height:30%;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you need [autocomplete](/questions/tagged/autocomplete)

```js
const input = $('#autocomplete');
const dropdown = $('#dropdown');
const countries = [{
    name: 'Afghanistan',
    code: 'AF'
  },
  {
    name: 'Åland Islands',
    code: 'AX'
  },
  {
    name: 'Albania',
    code: 'AL'
  },
  {
    name: 'Algeria',
    code: 'DZ'
  },
  {
    name: 'American Samoa',
    code: 'AS'
  },
  {
    name: 'AndorrA',
    code: 'AD'
  },
  {
    name: 'Angola',
    code: 'AO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Anguilla',
    code: 'AI'
  },
  {
    name: 'Antarctica',
    code: 'AQ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    code: 'AG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Argentina',
    code: 'AR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Armenia',
    code: 'AM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Aruba',
    code: 'AW'
  },
  {
    name: 'Australia',
    code: 'AU'
  },
  {
    name: 'Austria',
    code: 'AT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Azerbaijan',
    code: 'AZ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bahamas',
    code: 'BS'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bahrain',
    code: 'BH'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bangladesh',
    code: 'BD'
  },
  {
    name: 'Barbados',
    code: 'BB'
  },
  {
    name: 'Belarus',
    code: 'BY'
  },
  {
    name: 'Belgium',
    code: 'BE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Belize',
    code: 'BZ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Benin',
    code: 'BJ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bermuda',
    code: 'BM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bhutan',
    code: 'BT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bolivia',
    code: 'BO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
    code: 'BA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Botswana',
    code: 'BW'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bouvet Island',
    code: 'BV'
  },
  {
    name: 'Brazil',
    code: 'BR'
  },
  {
    name: 'British Indian Ocean Territory',
    code: 'IO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Brunei Darussalam',
    code: 'BN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bulgaria',
    code: 'BG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Burkina Faso',
    code: 'BF'
  },
  {
    name: 'Burundi',
    code: 'BI'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cambodia',
    code: 'KH'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cameroon',
    code: 'CM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Canada',
    code: 'CA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cape Verde',
    code: 'CV'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cayman Islands',
    code: 'KY'
  },
  {
    name: 'Central African Republic',
    code: 'CF'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chad',
    code: 'TD'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chile',
    code: 'CL'
  },
  {
    name: 'China',
    code: 'CN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Christmas Island',
    code: 'CX'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands',
    code: 'CC'
  },
  {
    name: 'Colombia',
    code: 'CO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Comoros',
    code: 'KM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Congo',
    code: 'CG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Congo, The Democratic Republic of the',
    code: 'CD'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cook Islands',
    code: 'CK'
  },
  {
    name: 'Costa Rica',
    code: 'CR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cote D\'Ivoire',
    code: 'CI'
  },
  {
    name: 'Croatia',
    code: 'HR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cuba',
    code: 'CU'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cyprus',
    code: 'CY'
  },
  {
    name: 'Czech Republic',
    code: 'CZ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Denmark',
    code: 'DK'
  },
  {
    name: 'Djibouti',
    code: 'DJ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dominica',
    code: 'DM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dominican Republic',
    code: 'DO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ecuador',
    code: 'EC'
  },
  {
    name: 'Egypt',
    code: 'EG'
  },
  {
    name: 'El Salvador',
    code: 'SV'
  },
  {
    name: 'Equatorial Guinea',
    code: 'GQ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Eritrea',
    code: 'ER'
  },
  {
    name: 'Estonia',
    code: 'EE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ethiopia',
    code: 'ET'
  },
  {
    name: 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',
    code: 'FK'
  },
  {
    name: 'Faroe Islands',
    code: 'FO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Fiji',
    code: 'FJ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Finland',
    code: 'FI'
  },
  {
    name: 'France',
    code: 'FR'
  },
  {
    name: 'French Guiana',
    code: 'GF'
  },
  {
    name: 'French Polynesia',
    code: 'PF'
  },
  {
    name: 'French Southern Territories',
    code: 'TF'
  },
  {
    name: 'Gabon',
    code: 'GA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Gambia',
    code: 'GM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Georgia',
    code: 'GE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Germany',
    code: 'DE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ghana',
    code: 'GH'
  },
  {
    name: 'Gibraltar',
    code: 'GI'
  },
  {
    name: 'Greece',
    code: 'GR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Greenland',
    code: 'GL'
  },
  {
    name: 'Grenada',
    code: 'GD'
  },
  {
    name: 'Guadeloupe',
    code: 'GP'
  },
  {
    name: 'Guam',
    code: 'GU'
  },
  {
    name: 'Guatemala',
    code: 'GT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Guernsey',
    code: 'GG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Guinea',
    code: 'GN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Guinea-Bissau',
    code: 'GW'
  },
  {
    name: 'Guyana',
    code: 'GY'
  },
  {
    name: 'Haiti',
    code: 'HT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands',
    code: 'HM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Holy See (Vatican City State)',
    code: 'VA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Honduras',
    code: 'HN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Hong Kong',
    code: 'HK'
  },
  {
    name: 'Hungary',
    code: 'HU'
  },
  {
    name: 'Iceland',
    code: 'IS'
  },
  {
    name: 'India',
    code: 'IN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Indonesia',
    code: 'ID'
  },
  {
    name: 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of',
    code: 'IR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Iraq',
    code: 'IQ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ireland',
    code: 'IE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Isle of Man',
    code: 'IM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Israel',
    code: 'IL'
  },
  {
    name: 'Italy',
    code: 'IT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jamaica',
    code: 'JM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Japan',
    code: 'JP'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jersey',
    code: 'JE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jordan',
    code: 'JO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Kazakhstan',
    code: 'KZ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Kenya',
    code: 'KE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Kiribati',
    code: 'KI'
  },
  {
    name: 'Korea, Democratic People\'S Republic of',
    code: 'KP'
  },
  {
    name: 'Korea, Republic of',
    code: 'KR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Kuwait',
    code: 'KW'
  },
  {
    name: 'Kyrgyzstan',
    code: 'KG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lao People\'S Democratic Republic',
    code: 'LA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Latvia',
    code: 'LV'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lebanon',
    code: 'LB'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lesotho',
    code: 'LS'
  },
  {
    name: 'Liberia',
    code: 'LR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya',
    code: 'LY'
  },
  {
    name: 'Liechtenstein',
    code: 'LI'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lithuania',
    code: 'LT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Luxembourg',
    code: 'LU'
  },
  {
    name: 'Macao',
    code: 'MO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of',
    code: 'MK'
  },
  {
    name: 'Madagascar',
    code: 'MG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Malawi',
    code: 'MW'
  },
  {
    name: 'Malaysia',
    code: 'MY'
  },
  {
    name: 'Maldives',
    code: 'MV'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mali',
    code: 'ML'
  },
  {
    name: 'Malta',
    code: 'MT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Marshall Islands',
    code: 'MH'
  },
  {
    name: 'Martinique',
    code: 'MQ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mauritania',
    code: 'MR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mauritius',
    code: 'MU'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mayotte',
    code: 'YT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mexico',
    code: 'MX'
  },
  {
    name: 'Micronesia, Federated States of',
    code: 'FM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Moldova, Republic of',
    code: 'MD'
  },
  {
    name: 'Monaco',
    code: 'MC'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mongolia',
    code: 'MN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Montserrat',
    code: 'MS'
  },
  {
    name: 'Morocco',
    code: 'MA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mozambique',
    code: 'MZ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Myanmar',
    code: 'MM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Namibia',
    code: 'NA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Nauru',
    code: 'NR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Nepal',
    code: 'NP'
  },
  {
    name: 'Netherlands',
    code: 'NL'
  },
  {
    name: 'Netherlands Antilles',
    code: 'AN'
  },
  {
    name: 'New Caledonia',
    code: 'NC'
  },
  {
    name: 'New Zealand',
    code: 'NZ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Nicaragua',
    code: 'NI'
  },
  {
    name: 'Niger',
    code: 'NE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Nigeria',
    code: 'NG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Niue',
    code: 'NU'
  },
  {
    name: 'Norfolk Island',
    code: 'NF'
  },
  {
    name: 'Northern Mariana Islands',
    code: 'MP'
  },
  {
    name: 'Norway',
    code: 'NO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Oman',
    code: 'OM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pakistan',
    code: 'PK'
  },
  {
    name: 'Palau',
    code: 'PW'
  },
  {
    name: 'Palestinian Territory, Occupied',
    code: 'PS'
  },
  {
    name: 'Panama',
    code: 'PA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Papua New Guinea',
    code: 'PG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Paraguay',
    code: 'PY'
  },
  {
    name: 'Peru',
    code: 'PE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Philippines',
    code: 'PH'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pitcairn',
    code: 'PN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Poland',
    code: 'PL'
  },
  {
    name: 'Portugal',
    code: 'PT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Puerto Rico',
    code: 'PR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Qatar',
    code: 'QA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Reunion',
    code: 'RE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Romania',
    code: 'RO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Russian Federation',
    code: 'RU'
  },
  {
    name: 'RWANDA',
    code: 'RW'
  },
  {
    name: 'Saint Helena',
    code: 'SH'
  },
  {
    name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
    code: 'KN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Saint Lucia',
    code: 'LC'
  },
  {
    name: 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon',
    code: 'PM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
    code: 'VC'
  },
  {
    name: 'Samoa',
    code: 'WS'
  },
  {
    name: 'San Marino',
    code: 'SM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sao Tome and Principe',
    code: 'ST'
  },
  {
    name: 'Saudi Arabia',
    code: 'SA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Senegal',
    code: 'SN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Serbia and Montenegro',
    code: 'CS'
  },
  {
    name: 'Seychelles',
    code: 'SC'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sierra Leone',
    code: 'SL'
  },
  {
    name: 'Singapore',
    code: 'SG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Slovakia',
    code: 'SK'
  },
  {
    name: 'Slovenia',
    code: 'SI'
  },
  {
    name: 'Solomon Islands',
    code: 'SB'
  },
  {
    name: 'Somalia',
    code: 'SO'
  },
  {
    name: 'South Africa',
    code: 'ZA'
  },
  {
    name: 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands',
    code: 'GS'
  },
  {
    name: 'Spain',
    code: 'ES'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sri Lanka',
    code: 'LK'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sudan',
    code: 'SD'
  },
  {
    name: 'Suriname',
    code: 'SR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen',
    code: 'SJ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Swaziland',
    code: 'SZ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sweden',
    code: 'SE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Switzerland',
    code: 'CH'
  },
  {
    name: 'Syrian Arab Republic',
    code: 'SY'
  },
  {
    name: 'Taiwan, Province of China',
    code: 'TW'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tajikistan',
    code: 'TJ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tanzania, United Republic of',
    code: 'TZ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Thailand',
    code: 'TH'
  },
  {
    name: 'Timor-Leste',
    code: 'TL'
  },
  {
    name: 'Togo',
    code: 'TG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tokelau',
    code: 'TK'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tonga',
    code: 'TO'
  },
  {
    name: 'Trinidad and Tobago',
    code: 'TT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tunisia',
    code: 'TN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Turkey',
    code: 'TR'
  },
  {
    name: 'Turkmenistan',
    code: 'TM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Turks and Caicos Islands',
    code: 'TC'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tuvalu',
    code: 'TV'
  },
  {
    name: 'Uganda',
    code: 'UG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ukraine',
    code: 'UA'
  },
  {
    name: 'United Arab Emirates',
    code: 'AE'
  },
  {
    name: 'United Kingdom',
    code: 'GB'
  },
  {
    name: 'United States',
    code: 'US'
  },
  {
    name: 'United States Minor Outlying Islands',
    code: 'UM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Uruguay',
    code: 'UY'
  },
  {
    name: 'Uzbekistan',
    code: 'UZ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Vanuatu',
    code: 'VU'
  },
  {
    name: 'Venezuela',
    code: 'VE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Viet Nam',
    code: 'VN'
  },
  {
    name: 'Virgin Islands, British',
    code: 'VG'
  },
  {
    name: 'Virgin Islands, U.S.',
    code: 'VI'
  },
  {
    name: 'Wallis and Futuna',
    code: 'WF'
  },
  {
    name: 'Western Sahara',
    code: 'EH'
  },
  {
    name: 'Yemen',
    code: 'YE'
  },
  {
    name: 'Zambia',
    code: 'ZM'
  },
  {
    name: 'Zimbabwe',
    code: 'ZW'
  }
];

input.on('input', () => {
  dropdown.html('');
  countries.map((country) => {
    if (country.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.val().toLowerCase())) {
      dropdown.append(`
        <div class="list-group-item">    
        ${country.name}
        </div>
        `);

    }
  });
  $('.list-group-item').on('click', (e) => {
    input.val(e.target.innerText);
    dropdown.html('');
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-wrapper {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="autocomplete" class="form-control">
<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
  <div id="dropdown" class="list-group">
  </div>
```